# error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: php, ssl, curl, sslv3

I'm trying to connect to a service that requires a certificate for authorization, I import certificates on my machine and when I directly hit on the server by my google chrome browser it give's me perfect result but when I call this URL from php curl request it gives me sslv3 alert handshake failure error.
(error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure)

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => SSLv3,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 7,
  CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 7,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

var_dump($response);
var_dump($err);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your cert to CURL and set any needed options

```
  $caFile = "ca.pem";
  $keyFile = "key.pem";
  $certFile = "client.pem";
  $certPass = "xxxxxx";

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $caFile);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyFile);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $certPass);
```

You can check the info for each CURL option [from here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: First of all Thanks for help,
Dear I have 3 certificate files and the extension of these files is .pfx
I import those certificates in my machine,
now i have to include by this way or firstly convert my files in .pem and then use it out

Comment: Sure, why not if solved my problem, I'll definitely Upvote it

Comment: Sure I'm waiting

Comment: You have to convert all to .pem before adding them to CURL, please follow [this link](https://www.xolphin.com/support/Certificate_conversions/Convert_pfx_file_to_pem_file)

Comment: I used conversion to pem certificates it just make an empty file can you please tell me what's the problem is

Comment: google it to see others that have the same issue and how did they solved it.

Comment: Dear can I change my .key file in to .pem also ??